# Convert Clusterfck array to JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit json hierarchical

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering, infovis

Currently I am using the javascript library [Clusterfck](http://harthur.github.com/clusterfck/) to perform a data grouping. This library generates an array in the following format:

```
[
  {"canonical":[20,120,102],
   "size":1
  },
  {"canonical":[250,255,253],
   "left":{
      "canonical":[250,255,253],
      "size":1
    },
   "right":{
      "canonical":[255,255,240],
      "size":1
    },
   "size":2
  },
  {"canonical":[100,54,300],
   "size":1
  }
]
```

But javascript libraries for data visualization how D3.js and [Jit](http://philogb.github.com/jit/index.html) using JSON structures as shown below:

```
{
    "canonical":"Pai",
    "children":[
        {"canonical":[20,120,102],  "size":1},
        {
            "canonical":[250,255,253],
            "children": [
                {"canonical":[250,255,253], "size":1},
                {"canonical":[255,255,240], "size":1}               
            ],
            "size":2
        },
        {
            "canonical":[100,54,300],
            "size":1
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to convert these structures, using JavaScript or PHP. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to convert between these structures, this is pretty simple. See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/vuk94/

```
function convert(input, rootName) {
    // top level
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        return {
            "canonical": rootName,
            "children": input.map(convert)
        };
    }
    // node
    else {
        ['left', 'right'].forEach(function(side) {
            if (input[side]) {
                input.children = input.children || [];
                input.children.push(convert(input[side]));
                delete input[side];
            }
        });
        return input;
    }
}
```

This uses a couple of ECMAScript 1.5 features (`Array.isArray`, `forEach`, and `map`), but if you're using d3 you're probably targeting browsers that support this anyway.